# jquery child selector problems

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a basic website nav layout that looks like this:

```
    <li class="folder parent_folder">
<a href="#">Some Folder</a>
<ul class="submenu">
    <li class="file"><a href="#">An awesome file</a></li>
    <li class="file"><a href="#">An awesome file</a></li>
    <li class="file"><a href="#">An awesome file</a></li>
    <li class="file"><a href="#">An awesome file</a></li>
    <li class="file"><a href="#">An awesome file</a></li>
    <li class="file"><a href="#">An awesome file</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have several of these throughout the site's page. Using jquery, I'm trying to make it so that when you click "li.parent_folder" "ul.submenu" disappears and then reappears when you click "li.parent_folder" again. I can get it to do this but I have a problem. When I click on the "li.parent_folder" all the "ul.submenu" disapear instead of just the one that is the child of it.

What would be the correct jquery code to accomplish this? (Oh, I'm using jquery ui also in this project

What I have right now is this:

$('li.parent_folder').click(function() {
    $('li.parent_folder > ul.submenu').hide();
});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Try this

```
$('li.parent_folder').click(function() {

  // +this+ var refers to the +li+ that was clicked.

  // .children() gets the children of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.
  $(this).children('ul.submenu').hide();
});
```

#### Here's more information on [`jQuery .children() method`](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

---

#### Edit:

updated method from `.find()` to `.children()` based on @Gumbo's recommendation

Comment: Better use `children` instead of `find`.

Comment: @Gumbo, I suppose you're right. `.children()` is more specific in that  it will look at the element's immediate descendants. Thanks :)

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. I used your technique but I changed it a bit. I need the "ul.submenu" to hide when I clicked the "li.parent_folder a" and not just the "li.parent folder". This was the final working code:

$('li.parent_folder a').click(function() {              $(this).parent('li.parent_folder').children('ul.submenu').hide();
});

thanks a lot!

Comment: oh...mind if I ask you one thing? 

What would I do if I wanted "ul.submenu" to show again when I clicked it the second time?

Comment: @codedude, jQuery provides a shortcut `$(this).children('ul.submenu').toggle();`

Comment: @codedue, you could also try `$(this).children('ul.submenu').slideToggle()` :)

Answer (score 1):

`$` does not maintain any kind of magical context - you'll have to tell it if you want to start looking from a certain element. In an even handler, `this` points to the element the handler is attached to. Try

```
$(this).find(">ul.submenu").hide();
```